# Android : Sd Card Validation

Tags: android, android-sdcard

How do i validate if the Sdcard is available or not? My application is save some voice to sdcard. If there's no memory card means, my app will force close. I don't know what can i do in that time. Could anyone please, how can i validate this before i've save the data to memory card.

**Update**

I've found for above this and got good answer from SO users also. Now, i want to check the Memory card size is full or not?  How can i done this? Anyone Guide Me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: +1 for your question, it is useful and most commonly needed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sdcard is mounted or not .....

```
if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

    // SD Card is mounted

} else {

    // SD Card is not mounted

}
```

Comment: Wow! I've used this method also. +1

Comment: How can i validate the size is full or not?

Comment: StatFs stat = new 
StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()); 
                long bytesAvailable = (long)stat.getBlockSize() * 
(long)stat.getBlockCount(); 
                long megAvailable = bytesAvailable / 1048576; 
the cast to long is necessary for cards larger than 4Gig.

Comment: Yes, this works pretty good and Please, update your answer. I'm going to accept your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've find a Way from [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Core-Class/returnTrueiftheexternalstorageisavailablewritable.htm).

It provides Simple way to Check that -

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state))
{
   //Whatever we want
}else
{
   //Whatever we want
}
```

Thanks for all of you Replying My Question.

Answer (score 0):

you can check [the external storage state](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState%28%29) before saving.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of different ways to do this, but the best one is probably to use [getExternalFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29). This will return null if the sdcard is not available. An added bonus is that it will be removed, when the user removes your application.

If you do not wish to use this feature, you can simply see if your directory exists, or if you can create it. Eg. `if(!dir.exists() && !dir.mkdirs())` then external storage is not available.